# GUA - Change Index To Any Value

Tags: google-analytics

I am upgrading from Google Analytics to Google Universal Analytics. I am wondering if it is possible to manually assign my dimensions its own index. For example, in Google Analytics, I have a Custom Variable with an index of 15. Will it be possible to assign a Dimension an index of 15, or do I have to start in a chronological order starting at 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create 14 custom dimensions (none that you have to use) to get to index 15. It'd be helpful if you could select the index though.

Comment: Is there any other alternative? I plan to upgrade to GUA Pro where I will have up to 200 Dimensions. If I need Dimension 187, I really don't want to create 186 dummy Dimensions. The code that maps the Dimensions are controlled else where, and I do not have access to that code.

Comment: You know I was thinking that you might be able to do it programmatically using the [management api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/), but I don't think it supports custom dimensions/metrics. If you are a premium client, I would try posting your question to the partners forum, and getting feedback directly from Google.